# P.D.E. problem Jacobi's Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve the following p.d.e. (from my assignment):
Find the complete integral of
$2u_1xz + 3u_2y^2 + (u_2)^2u_3 = 0 $ using Jacobi's Method

I got the characteristic equations as
$\frac{dx}{2xz} = \frac{dy}{3y^2+2u_2u_3} = \frac{dz}{(u_2)^2} = \frac{du_1}{-2u_1z} = \frac{du_2}{-6u_2y} = \frac{du_3}{-2u_1x}$

From this I get $\frac{dx}{x} =\frac{du_1}{-u_1}$ which gives
$u_1x = c$

However, I seem to have difficulties proceeding further.  Please help me out.

Comment: What are $u_{1}, u_{2}$ and $u_{3}$ supposed to represent? $u_{x}, u_{y}$ and $u_{z}$?

Comment: Yes. $u_1 = u_x, u_2 = u_y$  and $u_3 = u_z,$ i.e. the partial derivatives of u with respect to x, y and z respectively.